# AngularJS - ng-repeat with array checkboxes

Tags: arrays, angularjs

here's the demo:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0m3qc4s6/1/)

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    function Ctrl($scope) {

        $scope.selection = [];

        $scope.categories = [ { "name": "Sport", "id": "50d5ad" } ,
        {"name": "General", "id": "678ffr" } ];

    }
```

If i check any checkbox I need to see it's name in the array, but nothing happens, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a function that either add or delete an element on click, depending on the state of your checkbox :

[Updated JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5uyr8zxj/)

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="addToSelection(category)" ng-model="category.selected" name="group" id="{{category.id}}"/>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.addToSelection = function(category) {
            if (category.selected == true)
          $scope.selection.push(category.name);
        else
        $scope.selection.splice($scope.selection.indexOf(category.name),1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind listener for ng-change event. Something like

```
ng-change="selection.push(category.name)"
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0m3qc4s6/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change

```
$scope.selection = [];
```

with

```
$scope.selection = {};
```